# How to handle external API's JWT authentication from my Django application?

Tags: python, node.js, django, jwt

I am consuming an external RESTful API for my Django application, I want to understand how to handle JWT authentication for the API from my Django app

Following is the JWT token generation code as mentioned in the documentation:

```js
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync("./devSandbox.key","utf8");
var payload = {};
var currentTime =  Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
var signOptions = {
    algorithm: "RS512"
};

payload.iss = "adf50bf3-8b0f-479d-962d-4031ebadac9a";
payload.iat = currentTime;
payload.exp = currentTime + 1800;
payload.sub = "sbMem5c3418773ef071";

var token = jwt.sign(payload, privateKey, signOptions);
console.log("Printing token: "+ token);
```

Can someone please guide me as to how can I update my tokens from Django?
Currently, I have to manually run this code and update tokens wherever required?
Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Python. But since this Node.js code snippet is from API's document, you should follow the logic and convert node.js to python.

**What is JSON Web Token?**

> JSON Web Token (JWT) is an open standard (RFC 7519) that defines a compact and self-contained way for securely transmitting information between parties as a JSON object.

In short words, it's a two-way encrypted (or signed) JSON object that can be used as a trusted token or information. It is widely used with REST APIs because they're stateless and you cannot set session in the server.

**What is the JSON Web Token structure?**

> In its compact form, JSON Web Tokens consist of three parts separated by dots (.), which are:
>
> - Header
> - Payload
> - Signature

- Header contains signing algorithm used(SHA256 or RSA etc).
- Payload contains the actual data in JWT.

The payload may contain *[Registered claims](https://jwt.io/introduction/)* like the [follwing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token):

> **iss**: *Issuer* Identifies principal that issued the JWT.
>
> **sub**: *Subject* Identifies the subject of the JWT.
>
> **iat**: *Issued at* Identifies the time at which the JWT was issued. The value must be a NumericDate.
>
> **exp**: *Expiration Time* Identifies the expiration time on and after which the JWT must not be accepted for processing. The value must be a NumericDate either an integer or decimal, representing seconds past 1970-01-01 00:00:00Z.

**What's happening in the code?**

- [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) is a Node.js implementation of JWT.
- `jwt` (alias of `jsonwebtoken`) will sign your JWT using `privateKey` in the file named `devSandbox.key`. I suppose this key should have been provided by API provider.
- Sign algorithm is `RS512`.
- Issuer is set as `adf50bf3-8b0f-479d-962d-4031ebadac9a`. I suppose this is your `APP_ID` in REST API server.
- Expiration is set as 30 minutes.
- Subject is set as `sbMem5c3418773ef071`. This might be used in API provider for access control (for session, or user ID, stuffs like that).

**Suggestion**:

- Use a Python implementation of JWT to sign your token. For example: [python-jwt](https://pypi.org/project/jwt/)
- Attach generated jwt to your request header whenever you send a request to REST API in Python code. Curl example:

```
curl http://rest.api.server/api/ -H 'Authorization: Bearer {GENERATED_JWT}'
```